# grouping the sql statements in oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle11g

while grouping the sql statements in oracle stored procedure I am getting the error.please look in to my code select count(decode(msg_trans_type,'EXCH','Y',NULL)) EXCH INTO total_exchange_requests,                 count(decode(msg_trans_type,'BUY','Y',NULL)) BUY INTO total_buy_requests,                 count(decode(msg_trans_type,'SELL','Y',NULL)) SELL INTO total_sell_requests             from tra_message where msg_service_provider = in_svc_provider        AND trunc(msg_when_created) = to_date(in_start_date,'dd-mon-yyyy');  I am getting   Error(15,17): PL/SQL: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here please have a look and suggest your opinions.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong syntax.

Try:

```
select count(decode(msg_trans_type,'EXCH','Y',NULL)) EXCH,
       count(decode(msg_trans_type,'BUY','Y',NULL)) BUY,
       count(decode(msg_trans_type,'SELL','Y',NULL)) SELL
INTO total_exchange_requests, total_buy_requests, total_sell_requests
...
```